# Two-way SSL Client with Self-Signed Certificates

Tags: java, ssl, httpclient

I need to access a WebService that requires two-way SSL, my client (and their server) have self-signed certificates.

I only have the following code:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "path/myClient.key");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "pass");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "JKS");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "path/myClient.truststore");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "pass");
System.setProperty("com.sun.net.ssl.dhKeyExchangeFix", "true");
```

And I copied the TrustModifier to accept self-signed certificates from here:
http://java.dzone.com/articles/ignoring-self-signed

But still, I can't integrate the whole thing into the HttpClient to connect succesfully.

Any help?

Comment: You must not use the TrustModifier if you have certs in your store. The TrustModifier just disables cert checks. And please describe exception/error message you are getting.

Comment: You also need to change the trust settings on the server, if your client certificate is self signed. Rather than relaxing the trust settings, it's often better to import the self-signed certificates explicitly into the respective trust stores (otherwise, there's little point using SSL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server also needs to trust your client's certificate for the handshake to succeed at the server's end. Import your client's certificate into your server's truststore.